# Display two buses with same number on Google Maps

Tags: android, json

I've got bit of a problem with my project. I need to do application, that sending GPS coordinates in JSON from one Android application to server, and second Android application will pull this information from server and shows them on Google Maps.

My question is, what should I send in JSON, that I could recognize, for example, two buses with the same number, i.e: Two buses with number "17". On this time, I have this JSON:

{point : {lat : "50.00000", lng: "50.0000"}}

Comment: can you describe your problem more in detail? if you want to show those lat and lng you can create a marker on map and give those as coordinates

Comment: Yes I know. I did that and it worked. But my problem is when I've multiple android devices sending coordinates, and some of them sending coordinates from buses with same number i.e: "17" and i want display only one of this buses.

Comment: just a filter thorugh bus number and add only one marker in that case